# Determine if users can RDP after Windows Update

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop

I'm automating windows updates for a set of SQL servers, mostly running on Windows Server 2016. Typically after you install updates you have to reboot, and there is a period of time after rebooting where the server is applying updates and users can't remote into the server. In my automation, I would like to wait until that period of time is over before reporting a successful update. Is there an indicator that I can check remotely through powershell that will determine whether a user can remote in?

I've checked the main RDP services (termservice, SessionEnv and UmRdpService) during this period and they are all running, so if there's some sort of indicator, it isn't them. Maybe there is a field somewhere that states that windows is applying updates? All of the servers are virtualized through VMWare if it matters.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: This is probably better answered on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), as there isn't necessarily a specific "PowerShell" way of doing this. It's a complicated issue as there is no "clear" way to tell when everything is 100% ready: [How to check the restart status of a remote machine](https://superuser.com/questions/1029906/how-to-check-the-restart-status-of-a-remote-machine)

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask there; I've only ever posted on this site so thought I might have some luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have any luck on ServerFault either, but I did eventually find a solution myself, posting here in case anyone finds this thread looking for help.

The isn't actually a service that changes states when you can RDP back into a server; that's probably determined somewhere in the windows code and there's no way you could find the flag. However, the TIWorker program runs after a reboot to install windows, and in my experience recently, when that exe completes, you can RDP 100% of the time, which is good enough for my automation.

I loop over this piece of code in 5 second intervals until it returns 0 rows, then finish.

```
    Get-Process -ComputerName $server | ? {$_.ProcessName -match 'TiWorker'}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about *testing the port that the remote desktop service listens on*?

```
test-netconnection server -port 3389
```